# Paypal Sandbox randomly blocking payment

Tags: php, html, paypal, sandbox

I'm using Paypal for my online store (at least trying) and everything was OK until today: while testing with Paypal Sandbox, at the final step Paypal randomly says that the "Payment can't be finalized". I have no messages nor informations about what's happenning. 
I'll say it works 1 time out of 3.

I use IPN and everything is going right when Paypal doesn't block the payment. I use 3 Sandbox Accounts that are "Verified", one has a VISA credit card and the 2 others have no Credit Card but all of them have 3000+€ on the account.

I couldn't find a solution and it's been pretty annoying so I'd really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Not sure there's much that Stack Overflow can do for you here. This sounds like a question that might be better answered by Paypal customer support.

Comment: I have emailed paypal's support, still waiting for a reply though. Thanks for the advice Ben. What's annoying is being held in a situation where I don't know anymore where the problem could be from my code to paypal's servers.